# Can I create a shared data section in among a Linux process and forked sub-processes?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gcc, linker

I know this might be a strange requirement, but here it is:
I have to create a read-write section/segment in my x86-64 Linux ELF executable, so that this section can be shared among process and its sub-processes. I will handle any data synchronization requirement in the buffer, so pls do not worry about this trouble.

I know `mmap` can map 'shared' pages into my process, but for some reason, I cannot use `mmap` or similar functions. What I can do is to use a big `char` array. So far, I don't know if this is a mission impossible.

Here is my test code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

// reserve 20M bytes as JIT buffer
#define BUF_SIZE 20*1024*1024
char jit_buffer[BUF_SIZE] __attribute__((section(".buffer"), aligned(4096)));

int main()
{
    printf("pid=%d\n\n", getpid());
    printf(".main Start Address: %p\n", &main);
    printf(".buffer Start Address: %p\n", jit_buffer);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -o bssmap bssmap.c
```

after execution, I can check the .buffer section but only found that it is *private*, and I don't know whether and how to make it *shared*?

```
$ ./bssmap 
pid=557836

.text Start Address: 0x564e9637f189
.buffer Start Address: 0x564e96383000
```

in another terminal

```
$ cat /proc/557836/maps
564e9637e000-564e9637f000 r--p 00000000 08:02 7213494  bssmap
564e9637f000-564e96380000 r-xp 00001000 08:02 7213494  bssmap
564e96380000-564e96381000 r--p 00002000 08:02 7213494  bssmap
564e96381000-564e96382000 r--p 00002000 08:02 7213494  bssmap
564e96382000-564e97783000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 7213494  bssmap <-- 'private' but want 'shared'
```

btw, I know there is a 'shared' attribute in GCC manual, but it is for Windows and will be ignored with a warning while compiling in Linux.

Comment: When you say "a.out", do you really mean the ancient obsolete executable format that Linux used before ELF (until 1995: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out)?  I think you must not mean that because you have 64-bit addresses, and I don't know if Linux supported any 64-bit ISAs that early.  Possibly Alpha AXP?  But you also have 32-bit PIDs, and those look like PIE addresses, so all signs point to using a modern system, probably x86-64.  **So you don't have an "a.out executable", you have an ELF executable.**  You're not even using the default `a.out` name from GCC / `ld` so it's just confusing.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry for the confusing terminology. What I really mean is the 64-bit ELF executable on my x86_64 Ubuntu. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know mmap can map 'shared' pages into my process

Yes, *do* use `mmap`. Other possible answers: POSIX shared memory ([shm_open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) and friends) and SysV IPC ([shmat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shmat.3p.html) and friends).

> but for some reason, I cannot use mmap or similar functions.

You better figure out what "some reason" is, because you've just disallowed solutions which *can* work.

> What I can do is to use a big char array. So far, I don't know if this is a mission impossible.

That *will not* work. You can only share the "big char array" at the moment you `fork()`. Once you have two separate processes, not further communication through this array will be possible.

Comment: Instead of `fork`, can you manually use `clone` with any args to get selective sharing / unsharing of memory?  Seems like no, just `CLONE_VM` to share everything (like a new thread, not a new process).  But `mmap(MAP_SHARED)` stays shared even across fork, since it's backed by the same file, so yeah that seems the way to go, maybe using a file in `/tmp` that you delete after mmapping.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the information. I have learned some more knowledge.

Comment: @Employed Russian Thanks for the clear explanation and confirmation. The reason is 'my boss' and we probably will turn back to 'mmap' way. Luckily, he probably won't come here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read via `/proc/<pid>/mem`, e.g:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// reserve 20M bytes as JIT buffer
#define BUF_SIZE 20*1024*1024
char jit_buffer[BUF_SIZE] __attribute__((section(".buffer"), aligned(4096)));

void read_mem(char *desc, int pid, off_t address)
{
    int fd;
    char memfile[32];
    int val = 0;

    snprintf(memfile, sizeof(memfile), "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
    fd = open(memfile, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd >= 0) {
        if (pread(fd, &val, sizeof(val), address) == sizeof(val)) {
            printf("%s value=%d\n", desc, val);
        }
        close(fd);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pid_t fid = getpid();
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("fork() failed!\n");
        return 1;
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        *(int *)jit_buffer = 1;
        usleep(100000);
        read_mem("read child buffer:", pid, (long)jit_buffer);
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        *(int *)jit_buffer = 2;
        usleep(200000);
        read_mem("read parent buffer:", fid, (long)jit_buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample program. This a workaround to solve read/write issue. I want to share this 'big char array' among dozens of sub-processes via 'shared section' because this array leads to heavy burden to LLC cache. I will tell my boss this way is not doable and probably we will turn back to 'mmap' way.